# How to dynamically add widget inside a QStackedWidget

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qstackedwidget

In order to replicate the problem I have I prepared a small verifiable example.

I have 2 `QStackedWidgets` inside a `QGroupBox` with a couple more components as shown below:

[image: stack]

I created another widget called `QBoxForm` which carries a `QComboBox` only. 
This last widget should appear on the `QStackedWidget` on the left as soon as the `QCheckbox` is ticked.

[image: effect]

The `QStackedWidget` receive something because it becomes bigger but it does not show the `QComboBox`. How to make sure that a component is fully visible inside a `QStackedWidget`?

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mCombo = new CBoxForm;

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_checkBox_toggled(bool checked)
{
    if(ui->checkBox->isChecked())
    {
        if(checked)
        {
            ui->stackedWidget->insertWidget(0, mCombo);
            ui->stackedWidget->show();
        }
    }
    if(!ui->checkBox->isChecked())
    {
        ui->stackedWidget->removeWidget(mCombo);
    }
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "cboxform.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_checkBox_toggled(bool checked);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    CBoxForm *mCombo;
};
```

Lastly the additional combobox handled by another widget:

**cboxform.h**

```
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class CBoxForm;
}

class CBoxForm : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit CBoxForm(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~CBoxForm();

private:
    Ui::CBoxForm *ui;
};
```

**cboxform.cpp**

```
CBoxForm::CBoxForm(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::CBoxForm)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

CBoxForm::~CBoxForm()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**What I have done so far:**

1) I followed the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) and applied the method `insertWidget()` as advised. In fact [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#insertWidget) is what I have done exactly. This part works and can be confirmed by the fact that the `QStackedWidget` become larger as I check the box.

Also consequently I remove the widget in a similar way applying [removeWidget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#removeWidget) method available in the official documentation.

Everything seems to follow the correct functioning, but the only missing part is that I don't understand why the `QComboBox` does not appear on the `QStackedWidget` as I followed precisely the official documentation.

Any idea on what I might be missing or forgot to include in the above code?
Thanks for pointing in the right direction for solving this problem.

Comment: Did you put any layout into th QStackedWidget? I would try setting the minimum width and height for the QComboBox inside the CBoxForm. Also be sure to look at the correct page of your QStackedWidget item. Try **ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(0)** after  **ui->stackedWidget->insertWidget(0, mCombo)**

Comment: Thanks! :) The error was exactly what you pointed out. I should have inserted `ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(0)` after that statement. Thanks for catching the error. If you write the answer I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add **ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(0)** after **ui->stackedWidget->insertWidget(0, mCombo)** to make it visible.